# How can I center the caption above the table in "elsart" document class?

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment, captions, elsarticle

I am preparing a paper for Elsevier, then I used `elsart` document class. Tables are centered, but their captions are not centered. How can I solve this problem?

This is my code:

```
\documentclass{elsart}    
\usepackage{multirow}    
\usepackage{rotating}

\begin{document}    
\begin{table}[h!]    
\caption{....}    
\centering

\scalebox{1.5}{

\begin{tabular}{cc|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|l}

...

...

...

\end{tabular}}    
\label{tab:tab1}    
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

I'll be glad if someone help me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Gonzalo Medina has commented, consider to switch to `elsarticle.cls`. That said, here's a hack that adds `\centering` to `elsart`'s `\@maketablecaption`:

```
\documentclass{elsart}

\makeatletter
\long\def\@maketablecaption#1#2{\@tablecaptionsize
    \global \@minipagefalse
%    \hbox to \hsize{\parbox[t]{\hsize}{#1 \\ #2}}}% DELETED
    \hbox to \hsize{\parbox[t]{\hsize}{\centering #1 \\ #2}}}% ADDED

\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\caption{A caption}
\centering
(Tabular content)
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much, your answer was so useful for my problem. and as you and Gonzalo mentioned, I am trying to switch to "elsarticle" class.    regards, Mohammad.

Comment: @Mohammad You can only accept one answer, but you can (additionally) upvote every helpful one. ;-)

Answer (score 4):

You should consider using the improved `elsarticle` document class instead; this is what Elsevier says about `elsart` and `elsarticle`:

> Elsevier's previous document class for typeset articles, `elsart.cls`,
>   is now over 10 years old. It has been replaced with this newly written
>   document class `elsarticle.cls`, which has been developed for Elsevier
>   by the leading TeX developer River Valley Technologies.

Using `elsarticle`, you will have centered one-line captions by default:

```
\documentclass{elsarticle}    
\usepackage{lipsum}% just to generate text for the example

\begin{document}    

\lipsum[2]
\begin{table}
  \centering
  \caption{test caption}    
  \begin{tabular}{ll}
  test & test
  \end{tabular}
  \label{tab:tab1}    
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hello dear Gonzalo,
I change the document class to "elsarticle". But a problem stoped the compilation process.
The problem is: "Undefined control sequence.   \global\c@lastpage=13"       this error is in AUX file. what can I do to it?

Comment: my code is like below:

\documentclass{elsarticle}

\usepackage{subfigure}

\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows}

\usepackage{multirow}

\usepackage{url}

\usepackage{rotating}

\usepackage{setspace}

\doublespacing

\begin{document}

............

\nocite{*}

\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}

\bibliography{pose}

\end{document}

Comment: @Mohammad Try to delete all auxiliary files and compile again. If that doesn't help, ask a new (follow-up) question.

Comment: this problem is also solved by your answers. BUT now I lost my page style. according to my professor, my paper's pages should have a margin equal to 2.5cm from all the sides. and I used \oddsidemargin = 0cm
\topmargin = 0cm
\textheight = 25cm
\textwidth = 16cm
but now the pages height is not appropriate.(A4 page is 21*30 then I reduced 5cm from them and write 16*25 above). excuse me for my questions. I appreciate your kindness.

Comment: @Mohammad: but you said you are writing a paper for Elsevier, right? Then you should use the format provided by Elsevier and who else but Elsevier knows how they want their papers formatted. I don't understand what your professor's opinion has to do with this. I don't want to sound rude nor unpolite... It's just that I don't understand why you want to change the Elsevier format when writing a paper for Elsevier!